# How do I set the SNMP community string using Powershell DSC

Tags: powershell, snmp, dsc

I am deploying vanilla windows servers to be used in an application cluster.   I am using Powershell DSC to configure the nodes once they become alive.   I can ensure the SNMP Feature is installed, but I cant seem to find how to set the SNMP community strings for the SNMP Service

```
Configuration appNode
{
    Node localhost
    {
        WindowsFeature SNMP
            {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Name = "SNMP-Service"
            }
        DoSomethingMagicallyDelicious snmpCommunity
            {
            Community = "public"
            READONLY=$true
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am now using cSNMP (https://github.com/extenzo/cSNMP) and it works.  Someone remind me to create an answer for my current solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSC configures a system using resources - which are entities that can be modeled with a desired set of properties. In this specific case, a resource 'DoSomethingMagicallyDelicious' does not exist. We can either create one or see if we can use some other existing resource.

Based on this [article](http://www.vmwareadmins.com/using-powershell-install-snmp-configure-community-location-contact-windows-2008/) it looks like you can setup community using a registry key. The equivalent for setting (read only community) using DSC is as below

```
Registry PublicCommunity
{
    Key = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\ValidCommunities'
    ValueName = 'ReadOnlyCommunity'
    ValueType = 'DWord'
    ValueData = 4
}
```

You can model any other registry key required using a similar pattern